# How to deactivate Bootstrap's scrollspy for mobile viewports?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, navigation

I'm using the Bootstrap affix side-navigation as used in the [Bootstrap documentation](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html). As you can see there, the scrollspy doesn't make any sense when the viewport is smaller than 768px and the page is switching to mobile view. Hence, I want to deactivate the scrollspy as soon as the page switches to mobile viewe. Keep in mind that the fix should only apply on the sidebar-navigation – not on navbars. Ideas, anyone?

Answer (score 2):

The fix is easy enough. Use media queries and define position:static; for your sidebar-nav div for mobile views, eg

```
    @media (max-width: 767px){

   .sidenav.affix {         /* change sidenav selector to match your layout */   

    position: static;    /* removes the affix behaviour */
    width: auto;         /* customise as required */
    top: 0;               /* customise as required */
    }  
    }
```

Comment: thank you so much for this answer, spent like 2 hours on this one